# do i need to have [%systemroot%\system32] also when [%systemroot%] already is present in path?

Tags: environment-variables, path

Is there a need to *also* have [%systemroot%**system32**] or is that path already "covered" by [%systemroot%] ?

Comment: No, they are different paths.  Path environment doesn't cover sub-directories.  Also, I don't understand your `*` notation.  One other thing.. %systemroot% isn't actually the important one.  It is %systemroot%\\system32 that has all of the goodies in it.

Comment: thx! got it.   
(the asterisk as not important: ment to annotate system32 with both *italic* and **BOLD** then something "happened"